# Type 'Any' has no subscript members when printing array objects

Tags: swift, swift4

My error is on my print statement lines, it says type "Any" has no subscipt members...

```
if let urlContent = data {

                do {

                    let jsonResult = try 
JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with:urlContent, options: 
JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as AnyObject

                    print(jsonResult)

                    if let items = jsonResult["items"] as? NSArray {

                        for item in items  {

                        print(item["published"])
                        print(item["title"])
                        print(item["content"])
```

Comment: Please fix the indentation and post the whole code so that the error is reproducible in a playground

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need it as an array of dictionaries it seems.

```
if let items = jsonResult["items"] as? [[String: Any]] { 
    for item in items  {
        print(item["published"])
        print(item["title"])
        print(item["content"])
    }
}
```

Depending on what content you have in the dictionary you can replace `Any` in `[String: Any]` with that type. In this case it seems to be `String`.